# Calculate distance and only get one result for every trail_part_id

Tags: mysql, sql

What I want to achieve is to get only the closest result for every trail_part_id. However I am stuck, I tried to use GROUP BY trail_part_id, but that did not work either as I got the following error message:

> SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'p.latpoint' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I know I am missing something, please put me in the right direction.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(trail_part_id),
                  111.045 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(latpoint))
                      * COS(RADIANS(latitude))
                      * COS(RADIANS(longpoint) - RADIANS(longitude))
                      + SIN(RADIANS(latpoint))
                      * SIN(RADIANS(latitude)))) AS distance_in_km
FROM waypoints
JOIN (SELECT ' . $latitude . '  AS latpoint,  ' . $longitude . ' AS longpoint) AS p
ORDER BY distance_in_km ASC
```

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name. Having said that, I think your query is still incomplete. If you provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result, maybe we can help you writing a good query.

Comment: Sure @TheImpaler

My waypoints has columns id, trail_part_id, latitude, longitude

What I currently get is a list of all waypoints with its calculated distance_in_km. However I only want to get one row per trail_part_id. For example I only want to return the closest waypoint per trail_part_id, not every waypoint for every trail_part_id.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you, did not know that.

Comment: It's already said, but perhaps worth repeating... see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a few errors in my code.

1. As @a_horse_with_no_name explained, DISTINCT is not a function. So I removed it.
2. What I had to do was to select the lowest value of "distance_in_km" by wrapping it with MIN().

After this I did get the closest waypoint, and that was it, now I can use GROUP BY trail_part_id and get the expected result.